# ActiveResource for Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Would it make sense to use Meteor when you want to replace MongoDB with a solution like ActiveResource for Rails? I'm still figuring out if this is doable and makes sense.

Basically what I want to do is couple Meteor to an external API, but still keep it's features like latency compensation, live updates etc. But I can't seem to find any examples, other than: implementing the DDP protocol. But I don't want Meteor to have direct access to MongoDB (or whatever DB is behind the API). Which would mean it should be built into the Meteor collection.

Any tips?

Comment: *"I want to do is couple Meteor to an external API"* - what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: If you mean you want to use alternative DBs mongodb is the only official db at the moment. There's Meteor SQL but it doesnt have all the features